# Do we have to install Python or It is already installed in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Tags: 14.04, python, programming

I need it for learning Python language.
Please Help!

Comment: both python2 and 3 are installed by default on 14.04

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, both `python2` and `python3` are installed.

As already mentioned, you can check your version with either:

```
python -V
```

(mind the capital) or

```
python --version
```

or

```
apt-cache policy python
```

#### However

This will only show the version of `python2`, while on `14.04`, `python3` is installed as well. To see the version of `python3`, simply replace all occurrences of `python` in the commands above by `python3`

#### Note

If you start coding, also mind that using:

```
python <script>
```

will make python 2 run the code, and

```
python3 <script>
```

will make python 3 run it, and (if the script is executable), the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

will run it in python 2, and

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

will run it in python 3

#### Using Idle

As an answer to what you asked in a comment: *So it is the "terminal" where we do the coding,right!?*

The most convenient way is to use [Idle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29) (from the repositories). You can then test-run the code with <kbd>F5</kbd>, or if necessary from the terminal. It has the advantage that indentation is suggested automatically (a.o.)

Mind that you need to use different version of Idle for python 2 and 3.

Comment: Hi Jacob, I think your comment is the only answer this question needed. This is too detailed and misses the focus your comment has. Anyway, wanted to share it with you. Sometimes a one-line answer is enough. Your expertise can then be spent on other questions.

Comment: @don.joey I was doubting, you might be right :). However, the additional question element below Maythux answer made me think it is useful to add a few things...

Comment: So is "Idle" an application!?

Comment: Yes, it is a IDE for python, see the link in the answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29. You can install it (both Idle (2) and Idle3 from the software center.

Answer (score 4):

Check your python version with

```
python --version
```

Also note that there are some severe differences between python 2 and 3.
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Comment: You might want to add `python3 --version`, since it is installed by default as well. `python --version` only shows version of 2

Answer (score 3):

Python is installed by default in Ubuntu, but to check it:

Run this command

```
$ apt-cache policy python


python:
  Installed: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.3-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Thanks to @JacobVlijm note if you use Ubuntu >12.10 then you should use `apt-cache policy python3` instead

As you see under pyton section you can see       `Installed: 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2` This means it's installed and the version is 2.7

Also the `candidate` shows you the latest version available in your software channel, so you can upgrade your version if you want.

Comment: You might want to add `apt-cache policy python3` since `apt-cache policy python` only shows python2, while python3 is installed as well on 12.10 >

Comment: Installed: 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.4.0-0ubuntu2

This is what it is showing after using this command `apt-cache policy python3`.
So it means I have the latest 3.4.0 right!?

Comment: @MervinJacob That is correct.

Comment: As I told you guys I need Python for programming.
So it is the "terminal" where we do the coding,right!?

Comment: @MervinJacob the Python REPL is nice. REPLs are nice in general. I don't think you want to code an enterprise-grade application in the terminal, though. You should clarify what you have actually set to achieve. (Also, I smell homework, if so you might want to ask your teacher or TA directly).

Comment: @TobiaTesan
I am planning to join "Programming for Everybody (Python)" by Coursera
(http://www.coursera.org/course/pythonlearn/).
They will give  detailed instructional videos for both Windows and Macintosh computers for all software installation but not for Linux.
So that why I had soo many doubts!

Comment: Guys should I use 'Visual Studio Code'!?

Comment: @MervinJacob: use whatever you like/whatever is required by your instructor. Without specific requirements, any editor is as good as any other. After all, Emacs and Vim fanboys have been arguing with each other for more than 20 years (which is funny since Emacs is clearly the superior choice :P ). I think this is not relevant to the question. StackExchange is *not* a forum; in fact "Can Visual Studio do X" is probably another question.