# dpkg: error processing package mendeleydesktop (--install)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mendeley

Now I am sick of this error and after trying all the things that I found from similar questions, I decided to post this. So I am trying to install [mendeleydesktop](https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/) on my newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 :

`sudo dpkg -i mendeleydesktop_1.16.1-stable_i386.deb`

But it throws the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 248304 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mendeleydesktop_1.16.1-stable_i386.deb ...
Unpacking mendeleydesktop (1.16.1) over (1.16.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mendeleydesktop:
 mendeleydesktop depends on python.

dpkg: error processing package mendeleydesktop (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mendeleydesktop
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But this doesn't get rid of the error. I would be very happy if somebody could solve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I think. How do I check that otherwise?

Comment: like this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckingYourUbuntuVersion

Comment: I mean I know that I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I was not sure that it is 32-bit so I asked how can I check that.

Comment: @edwinksl : After running command `uname -i`,  I see `x86_64` so I think that the architecture is 64-bit.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Type `arch` in the terminal and let me know what it says.

Comment: @edwinksl : Thanks. Your comment solved my problem. So I was incorrectly using 32-bit package for a 64 bit architecture. (arch says `x86_64`).

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Try installing the 64-bit version of the package and see if that helps.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem in ubuntu 18.04. I solved it with:

sudo apt --fix-broken install

Then try to install the program again.
It worked for me.

Comment: For me this approach worked as well on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score -1):

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mendeleydesktop:
>    mendeleydesktop depends on python.

Check if python is still installed like here: [Do we have to install Python or It is already installed in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630142/do-we-have-to-install-python-or-it-is-already-installed-in-ubuntu-14-04lts)

Comment: OP did say his Ubuntu 14.04 is freshly installed, so I doubt he had uninstalled `python`.

Comment: Python is installed by default. I can use it to run my python codes.